# Battery Type Buck Converter With Bootstrap MOSFET Driver

Tags: mosfet, pwm, buck, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

I have a device that used 2x 1.2 V NiMH batteries that I want to change to use a Li-Ion cell. I want to map the 3.3 - 4.2 V voltage range of the Li-Ion to the 2.0 - 2.4 V of the NiMH using PWM.

I use an external charger so there is no problem charging.

I use an AVR microcontroller to measure its own VCC which is the Li-Ion voltage and outputs PWM with a calculated dutycycle that would output 2.0 to 2.4 V.

THE PROBLEM:
The power electronics shown in the schematic, I use a high-side N-channel MOSFET, its gate is pulled to the bootstrap voltage with a resistor then a NPN transistor pulls it ground as the PWM goes high. The output voltage swings to over 3 volts when the PWM is 254.

NOTE:

1. Since the NPN transistor turns off the MOSFET, the PWM is inverted so 254 should give just a few mV.
2. The inductor is currently out of stock so I just put a short instead.
3. I don't care about the efficiency or the state of charge calculation of the Li-Ion.
4. The PWM frequency should be 31.25 kHz
5. There is no SMD MOSFET driver available right now and I have to keep the PCB as small as possible.
6. Maybe ditch the bootstrap design and put the mosfet on the low-side?

[image: Power Electronics Schematic]

Comment: You need a diode or sync FET from the source of your FET to ground.  Replacing the inductor with a short because it's out of stock is not a good idea, and your FET driver isn't ideal.  You need a high side switch of some sort so not sure how you would ditch the bootstrap and put the FET on the bottom side.

Comment: C2 should be a schottky diode. There a plenty of single chip solutions that will do what you want more simply.

Comment: C2 is clearly bad design.

Comment: @JohnD the capacitors and inductor at the source were only meant for filtering the PWM. Ditching the high side switch meaning I will PWM the ground of the load and connect its VCC directly to the battery.

Comment: @YoussefAly97, OK, if your load can work with direct PWM (some can and some can't), and it doesn't interface to anything else that requires a common ground, then direct PWM of a low-side switch is perfectly acceptable.  But driving capacitors directly with a high side switch isn't the way to go.  It will result in very high spikes of current from your batteries, or even collapse of the input voltage.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing C2 with a schottky, L1 with a real inductor (SMD 0805) of an unknown value (too small for my meter to measure, less than 10uH or too low Q factor). Drove the circuit at 100 Khz with a PWM resolution of 80 bits. Works like a charm!